# Probability of non-uniform draw without repeats.

Tags: probability

I'm programming a machine that places one of eleven balls in sequence. The probabilities of the machine picking ball $i$ is given by $p_i$, and not necessarily does $p_i=p_j$ (this is what I mean by non-uniform).

The machine first picks a ball $i$, and notes its number. If $i$ is then picked again, it redraws until $j$ is picked.

Given ball $i$ is drawn first, what is the probability of ball $j$ being drawn second? (And then of ball $k\neq i,j$ being drawn third.)

My conjecture is that given ball $i$ is first, I can simply multiply all $p_{j\neq i}$ with a scalar $\alpha$ so that $\sum \alpha p_{j\neq i}=1$. I think I can prove this works with $p_i=p_j$, but I don't know if it generalizes.

Comment: This is not clear.  What does "If ball i is chosen for container one, then if ball i is also chosen for container two" mean?  Can a ball go into more than one container?

Comment: I'm sorry if it's unclear. The machine "thinks" that each ball can go in multiple containers, but if it picks a repeat, we tell it to pick again until it gets one that doesn't repeat. I'll try to edit.

Comment: I think, but am not sure, that the "containers" are just confusing things.  You are trying to make three distinct draws.  Each time you draw you replace the ball you drew, but you note its number.  If you ever draw it again, you put it back and redraw.  So it is just as if you removed it.  Yes?

Comment: Assuming I am right, then the probabilities just rescale, exactly as you have written.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean, I'll rewrite. Okey, thank you. I'll accept your answer if you want to write one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I am interpreting the question:  You are trying to draw three distinct balls from the collection.  Each time you draw a ball you note its number and replace it.  Should you draw that number again, you put it back and repeat the draw.

Under this scenario, the probabilities just rescale by a constant factor, as imagined in the original post.  To see that, let's suppose you first draw ball $1$.  Let $\hat {p_2}$ be the probability that the next draw is ball $2$.  Indeed, three things can happen on the next draw:  you get ball $2$, you get one of $3,\cdots, 11$, you get ball $1$ again.  Thus $$\hat {p_2}=p_2\times 1+ (p_3+\cdots +p_{11})\times 0 + p_1\times \hat {p_2}=p_2+p_1\times \hat {p_2}\implies \hat {p_2}=\frac {p_2}{1-p_1}$$

Nothing special about ball $2$ of course, all the probabilities just scale by $\frac 1{1-p_1}$ and we are done.